# Is it possible Migrate Azure Redis Cache to other subscription?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using Azure Redis Cache from Subscription A, I want to change the Current subscription (A) of redis to B (new Subscription).

a - Is it possible? How? if not 
b - Can i Persist Same Access keys for new Redis created under B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the list of services that can be moved across subscriptions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/, I would say it is possible to move Redis Cache from one Azure Subscription to another.

[image]

Regarding how you could move the resources, you can do it using `Azure Portal`, `Azure PowerShell`, `Azure CLI tools` or even `Azure REST API`. Please see the link for instructions on how you can accomplish this.

Comment: Moving the Resource will change the Access keys?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself so I wouldn't know for sure. But taking a wild guess, I would imagine it would preserve the access keys. I would recommend trying it out by creating a new REDIS cache and move that instead of moving your existing cache.

Comment: Thank you! one more question. what if the Subscription B is under other Account? Is it still possible to move?

Comment: :) :) .... my friend, you need to try it out yourself. Given that authentication mechanism for Azure REST API is Azure AD based which makes use of the token issued to the user, I'm inclined to say that if Subscription B is under other user account, then you will not be able to move resources. But again, please give it a try yourself.

Comment: If the Subscription B is under other account, you cannot move resources from Subscription A to B, because A and B have 2 different tenants. If you want to move resources across subscriptions, the subscriptions must share the same tenant.

Comment: @Gaurav , Jack  - i have just moved my entire subscription from 1 account to other and found it is possible to move redis in it also. i faced a little problems in Service Bus migration except everything was smooth. Thank you guys for help! :)